# Weird NSUnknownKeyException only on Iphone X

Tags: ios, iphone-x

We are getting this crash report from Crashlytics.

```
Fatal Exception: NSUnknownKeyException
[<UIStatusBar_Modern 0x10401da70> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key foregroundView.

    0  CoreFoundation                 0x1865e9d04 __exceptionPreprocess
    1  libobjc.A.dylib                0x185838528 objc_exception_throw
    2  CoreFoundation                 0x1865e99cc -[NSException init]
    3  Foundation                     0x186f92864 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) valueForUndefinedKey:]
    4  Foundation                     0x186ed8f70 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) valueForKey:]
    5  APP                            0x10071757c +[RMSystemInformation getUserNetworkType] (RMSystemInformation.m:253)
    6  APP                            0x10073e9b8 -[RMReachability currentReachabilityString] (RMReachability.m:420)
    7  APP                            0x10071ce54 __16-[RMConfig init]_block_invoke (RMConfig.m:197)
    8  APP                            0x10073ed78 -[RMReachability reachabilityChanged:] (RMReachability.m:443)
    9  APP                            0x10073e3d8 TMReachabilityCallback (RMReachability.m:83)
    10 SystemConfiguration            0x1872dabcc reachPerformAndUnlock
    11 libdispatch.dylib              0x185f6d088 _dispatch_call_block_and_release
    12 libdispatch.dylib              0x185f6d048 _dispatch_client_callout
    13 libdispatch.dylib              0x185fab1c0 _dispatch_queue_serial_drain$VARIANT$armv81
    14 libdispatch.dylib              0x185fabb30 _dispatch_queue_invoke$VARIANT$armv81
    15 libdispatch.dylib              0x185fac528 _dispatch_root_queue_drain_deferred_wlh$VARIANT$armv81
    16 libdispatch.dylib              0x185fb45c4 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread$VARIANT$armv81
    17 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x186212fd0 _pthread_wqthread
    18 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x186212c20 start_wqthread
```

It occurs to hundreds of users and only in iPhone X. Seems that all the classes that appear in the report like UIStatusBar_Modern or RMReachability are from private API.

Also, we can't reproduce it in the simulator so any help will be welcome.

Any idea on how to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: This reads like some third-party library (RedMinePM?) that doesn't understand the network type that's being returned when it's detecting network connectivity changing; but without any more details, this is just guessing.

Comment: We reproduce it by turning on and off the flight mode in a real device. Now we are looking which of our dependencies have the problem. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: Found any solution ? I am getting it on iPhoneX Simulator. I think it is because of different type of status bar in X

Comment: In my case was an old library that we weren't using. We removed the library and fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The status bar in iPhone X is nested more than one layer.

The handle code is as follows：

```
 NSArray *subviews = nil;
id statusBar = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] valueForKey:@"statusBar"];
if ([statusBar isKindOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"UIStatusBar_Modern")]) 
{
    subviews = [[[statusBar valueForKey:@"statusBar"] valueForKey:@"foregroundView"] subviews];
} 
else 
{
    subviews = [[statusBar valueForKey:@"foregroundView"] subviews];
}
```

Reference taken from [here](https://github.com/pili-engineering/PLPlayerKit/issues/328)

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue when I tried to run my app on iPhone x. After struggling 3 days on this finally I found a solution. I tried to remove external libraries (SDKs) one by one and then I was able to catch the library which was causing this issue. In my case, Applovin was producing issue. As I have stopped using it way before so I didn't try to update and use again in code. If you need to use then prefer to update it to the latest.

Cheers!

Comment: I think that might actually be a red herring, as I use AppLovin in multiple ranked apps and have never got this exception before.